# Slack appender for log4j2

Tags: java, maven, log4j2, slack

i am trying to use Slack appender for log4j2 by tobias, in Java 8 project with maven.
The tobias project is:
[tobias wrapper for slack](https://github.com/tobias-/slack-appender)

I am trying to configure the appender or by log4j2.xml file or by programatic configuration, and both ways i can't get it to work.

My log4j4.xml file is:

```
<configuration monitorInterval="30">
<appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%-5p - [%t]"/>
    </Console>

    <Slack name="Slack" channel="configurouter-alerts">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p - [%t]"/>
    </Slack>

</appenders>

<loggers>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Slack" level="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>
</loggers>
</configuration>
```

My maven dependencies are:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>slackappender</groupId>
<artifactId>slackappender</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.olsson</groupId>
        <artifactId>slack-appender</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

I am getting this error log:

```
2018-09-17 12:07:38,815 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class be.olsson.slackappender.SlackAppender for element Slack: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Didn't find any working be.olsson.slackappender.client.Client implementation called null java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:513)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:249)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at LoggingUtils.lambda$startLogging$1(LoggingUtils.java:70)
    at LoggingUtils.startLogging(LoggingUtils.java:25)
    at LoggingUtils.startLogging(LoggingUtils.java:70)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Didn't find any working be.olsson.slackappender.client.Client implementation called null
    at be.olsson.slackappender.SlackAppender.findClientImpl(SlackAppender.java:326)
    at be.olsson.slackappender.SlackAppender.createAppender(SlackAppender.java:310)
    ... 28 more

2018-09-17 12:07:38,822 main ERROR Null object returned for Slack in appenders.
2018-09-17 12:07:38,826 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "Slack" for logger config "root"
2018-09-17T12:07:38,938 [main] [INFO ] [flow=] [phase=] [uid=] [url=] [] Main - logging started
2018-09-17T12:07:38,940 [main] [INFO ] [flow=] [phase=] [uid=] [url=] [] Main - Info logger.
2018-09-17T12:07:38,940 [main] [ERROR] [flow=] [phase=] [uid=] [url=] [] Main - Warning logger.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does someone that uses this tobias wrapper with maven and know hoe to help?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't use this appender, but as I can see in the `build.gradle` file in [it's github repo](https://github.com/tobias-/slack-appender/blob/master/build.gradle#L95), you need to manually add the HTTP client implementation to your runtime classpath. Those are the libs the author uses in the project:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    provided 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that solved the problem!
I added to the pom the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```